# Not all posts are showing on Template page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I made a custom template and I want to show all posts from certain category in this template excluding some ,I am only getting 10 posts but I have more than 100 posts and pagination shows repeated posts ,I mean same posts on other pages ,is there anything wrong in this code

any help would be highly appreciated

`

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
$homepageLayout = get_theme_mod('homepageLayout', 'no-sidebar');

?>

<div class="container pm-containerPadding-top-110 pm-containerPadding-bottom-90">
    <div class="row">

        <?php if($homepageLayout === 'no-sidebar') { ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">




                <?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');


 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php } else if($homepageLayout === 'right-sidebar') {?>

            <!-- Retrive right sidebar post template -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">

                <?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');



 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>  

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

             <!-- Right Sidebar -->
             <?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>
             <!-- /Right Sidebar -->

        <?php } else if($homepageLayout === 'left-sidebar') { ?>

             <!-- Left Sidebar -->
             <?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>
             <!-- /Left Sidebar -->

            <!-- Retrive right sidebar post template -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">

                <?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');



 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php } else {//default full width layout ?>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

<?php

$query = new WP_Query('cat=106,93,138,136,86,23,103,83,84,92,78,137');



 if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <?php }//end of posts ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                     <p><?php _e('No posts were found.', 'medicallinktheme'); ?></p>
                <?php } ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'pagination' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php }  ?>

    </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Go to Wordpress Admin Dashboard

There is in Setting > Reading

A Option Available "Blog pages show at most" that is default 10 change it and you can get all your posts

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply ,I have set it up but pagination shows same posts whether I go to 1st page or 4th or any other,I see same posts ,I want to have different posts not same ,I think there is something wrong with the code ,I am not able to figure it out

Comment: You need to included the paged parameters within the wp_query to support pagination, but you should post another question for that.